# Pandas multiindex: select by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm failing with accessing the values from multi-index/columns DataFrame by condition.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4),
                  index=[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], ["c", "d", "c", "d"]],
                  columns=[['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat2'], ['vals1', 'vals2', 'vals1', 'vals2']])
```

```
     cat1        cat2      
    vals1 vals2 vals1 vals2
a c     0     1     2     3
  d     4     5     6     7
b c     8     9    10    11
  d    12    13    14    15
```

I know how to access values|subframes by their position e.g.

```py
df.loc[("a", "c"), ("cat1", "vals1")]
df.loc[(slice(None), "d"), ("cat1", slice(None))]
```

**BUT how to use the condition here**

e.g. select the value in column ("cat1", "vals2") where ("cat2", "vals2")==7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tuples in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = df.loc[df[("cat2", "vals2")] == 7, ('cat1', 'vals1')]
print (a)
```

Last if need scalar from one element `Series`:

```
out = a.iat[0]
```

If possible no match:

```
out = next(iter(a), 'no match')
```

You can compare sliced rows, columns - output is DataFrame filled by boolean - so for boolean `Series` need test if any True per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or all Trues per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
m = df.loc[:, ("cat2", slice(None))]==7

a = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), ("cat1", "vals2")]
print (a)
a  d    5
Name: (cat1, vals2), dtype: int32
```

---

```
m = df.loc[:, ("cat2", slice(None))]==7
df2 = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), ("cat1", slice(None))]
print (df2)
     cat1      
    vals1 vals2
a d     4     5
```

Comment: Thx, and if I'd like to not specify second level column `"vals2"` explicitly? It seems that using `slice(None)` doesn't work there.

Comment: @HonzaS. - hmmm, can you be more specific? I add code for compare sliced rows and columns, question is how is necessary next processing?

Comment: let's consider the condition `df.loc[:, ("cat2", slice(None))]==7`. It gives me a boolean dataframe.  I'd need to get the value of column `("cat1", "vals2")` for row where the above condition evaluates to True  ... 5 in the example case.

Comment: @HonzaS. - solution was changed.

Comment: perfect, now it is really universal solution for my case

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df[('cat2', 'vals2')].eq(7), ('cat1', 'vals2')]
```

output:

```
a  d    5
Name: (cat1, vals2), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

A very similar approach to @mozway would be the use of pd.IndexSlice, as [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) suggests in the "Using Slices" section.

```
idx = pandas.IndexSlice

mask = df[('cat2', 'vals2')]==7

df.loc[idx[mask], idx['cat1', "vals2"]]
```

Comment: thx, I like this mask used in the `IndexSlice`